# Initialize nil pointer when the type is interface{}

Tags: go, reflection

I was wondering how to initialize a nil pointer to a struct, when the `initialize` function receives this argument as `interface{}`.

How can I make this code work assuming that I will always be sending a pointer, and the type of the argument of the function is strictly `interface{}`?

```golang
type Foo struct {
}

func main() {
    var foo *Foo
    fmt.Println("foo is nil: ", foo)
    initialize(foo)
    fmt.Println("foo should not be nil: ", foo) // foo should be Foo{}, but it is nil
}

func initialize(fooPointer interface{}) {
    reflect.ValueOf(&fooPointer).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(&Foo{}))
    fmt.Println("fooPointer is not nil: ", fooPointer)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Va0bqXJGhWZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To modify a variable in a called function, the address of the variable must be passed to the called function.

Use this code:

```
func main() {
    var foo *Foo
    fmt.Println("foo is nil: ", foo)
    initialize(&foo)  // <-- Pass address of variable
    fmt.Println("foo should not be nil: ", foo) // foo should be Foo{}, but it is nil
}

func initialize(fooPP interface{}) {
    // No need for & here because fooPP is a **Foo.
    reflect.ValueOf(fooPP).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(&Foo{}))
    fmt.Println("fooPointer is not nil: ", fooPointer)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/omxTKhwOPSj).